# Need to open/edit SSRS reports copied from a local computer to a shared drive

Tags: reporting-services, location, ssrs-2008, rdl

I need to make updates to several SSRS reports. The problem is, these were originally developed on another developer's local computer. He quit suddenly and the SSRS project was copied to a shared drive by a manager. The original computer with the original SSRS project is no longer available.

I can launch the project, but when I try to open any of the rdls for editing I get an error message: "Could not find part of the path 'C:\Users\jsmith\Downloads\upload\3 Site Kits On Time.rdl'." Clearly, it's looking for files on the other programmer's C drive, which no longer exists.

Is there a way to get the rdls to open in the new location? The new path would be \\DataMgt\SSRSPackages\CTReports.

This is SSRS 2008. There is no version control (don't ask).

Comment: You are correct in identifying that the project file is looking for a specific file in a specific location.   To get around this have you tried creating a new SSRS project in Visual studio, and re-adding all the rdls by 'Adding Existing item' to this new project?

Comment: You might also consider manually editing the Visual Studio project file. You could search for the base file path (like C:\Users\jsmit\Downloads) and then replace them with the correct path. Of course, the VS project system doesn't allow multiple publish folders. This means you have a separate project for each folder that you want to publish to.

Comment: Creating a new project and importing all the reports into it seems to have done the trick, Jonnus - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Just to make this a formal answer as it seems to have worked fort the question setter...)

You are correct in identifying that the project file is looking for a specific file in a specific location.

To get around this you can create a new SSRS project in Visual studio, and then add all the rdls to those new project by inserting them to the new project by right-clicking the project, selecting 'Add' then 'Existing item...' and choosing the report files.